# Tables created in Snappy-shell/snappy-sql do not show up smart connector mode | java

Tags: snappydata

The sparkcontext is created as below

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(args[0]);
snappySes = new SnappySession(new SparkSession.Builder().config("spark.snappydata.connection", "localhost:1527").getOrCreate())
```

Read snappy data

```
snappySes.table("SNAPPY_COL_TABLE").show(10);
```

Job submitted as below

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/spark2/bin/spark-submit --conf --conf snappydata.connection=localhost:1527 --conf spark.ui.port=0 --master local[*] --driver-memory 2g --jars  --deploy-mode client --conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=/root/snappydata-1.0.1-bin/jars/* --conf  spark.executor.extraClassPath=/root/snappydata-1.0.1-bin/jars/* --class myclass
```

Job is connecting to snappydata ,logs below

> Initializing SnappyData in cluster mode: Smart connector mode: sc =
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext@164d01ba, url =
>   jdbc:snappydata://localhost[1527]/

But fails with table not found.This is pointing to a different store
different tables are listed

If the same job is submitted with snappy's sparksubmit. Works as expected. 
Only change is submitting job is

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.2.0-205/spark2/bin/spark-submit --- fails
/root/snappydata-1.0.1-bin/bin/spark-submit ---- Pass
```

Comment: Hi Satish, which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @plambre : I am using spark 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are running two snappydata clusters. And, somehow your `localhost` is not resolving uniformly? If you stop the snappy cluster do you get an exception when you submit to HDP ?

Comment: I have found the root cause the hive-site.xml in the spark conf was the issue.After removing it the connection was to existing/running snappy data.But this conf file cannot be removed so turned the code to jdbc connection